# Resource loading into ArrayList for tile-based game. (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, resources, tile

So i'm attempting to develop a tile-based game using eclipse, and i have run into a problem on how to load the resources from the resource folder into an ArrayList. I have a file reader that can load all of the needed files
into a list, but i can't use class folders for each tile type (grass, stone, etc) because an ArrayList can only store one class type. Is there a way to load all sub-classes of the tile super-class into a single ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a parent class (or interface) that all of the other classes extend from, then you can simply use an ArrayList of that parent class. Just create an ArrayList of Tiles.

```
List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();

Tile a = new GrassTile(); //GrassTile extends Tile
Tile b = new StoneTile(); //StoneTile extends Tile

tiles.add(a);
tiles.add(b);

for(Tile t : tiles){
   t.doTileStuff();
}
```

Edit: You could also reconsider your design and try to favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Instead of having a bunch of classes that extend Tile, have a single Tile class that contains attributes that determine how it behaves and looks.

Answer (score 0):

If the tiles that you are trying to put into a single arraylist is sub-class of a superclass, then you can set your arraylist to take in type superclass while disguising your subclasses into your superclass.